# Using filter with match doesn't filter out records

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array object named `data`. I render it's properties in a table and I want to implement search functionality where I enter an `id` to fetch it's corresponding data. Here is the code I used for fetching all of `data` array object into a table.

Filter.js (minimal code)

```
 <h2>Search filtering</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="search"
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        />
 <TableBody>
              {data?.companyProfileDtos?.filter((name) => name.match(new RegExp(searchValue, "i")))
                ?.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row) => (
                  <TableRow
                    key={row.name}
                    sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                  >
                    <TableCell align="center" component="th" scope="row">
                      {row.id}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{row.companyName}</TableCell>

                    <TableCell align="center">{row.emailAddress}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{row.phoneNumber}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{row.city}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{row.companyRating}</TableCell>

                   
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
```

**The  problem is**
**When I add** `.filter((name) => name.match(new RegExp(searchValue, "i")))` **in to my code, it returns to a blank screen.**

What is my mistake here? Thanks

Comment: Please add how the data looks like, a sandbox would be much easier to answer ...

Comment: It appears that `data.companyProfileDtos` is an `array` of `objects` (where each object may have props such as: `companyName`, `emailAddress`, `city`, etc). So, the iterator `name` may be an `object`. Consequently `name.match` tries to match reg-ex on the object. Is that your intention? May be try `filter((row) => row.name.match` ?

Comment: It works. you helped a developer! Thanks